# Magento 2 Mageplaza social login module for hÿva not working properly

Tags: magento

I hope you're all doing fine, I come to this forum because I couldn't find an answer to my problem. I'm working on adding a social login on a Magento 2.4.5 instance with [Mageplaza social login module](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-login-extension/?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=Social%20Login&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&a=bigvn). I also installed a social login compatibilty module for Hŷva as I am suing Hŷva theme on this project.

The problem I got is the following one, when I first log in (account creation) using facebook everything runs fine. The issue occurs when I try to log in again later using the same account. I simply can't access my account and I got a popup asking for a password and password confirm.

[password confirm popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R05g.png)

I double checked enverything related to configuration (META and Magento) but I strongly supect that the issue comes from the compatibily module for hyva that might be outdated.

I'd like to know if someone already encountered this issue and might give me some info on it.